# Enable language selector for Paragraphs Library

Tags: i18n-l10n, paragraphs, 9

I am using paragraphs on a multilingual Drupal 9 page. Everything is working fine, I can translate basic pages with paragraphs to get a multilingual node.

I have now enabled the Paragraphs Library sub module, but I can't enable the language support for that.

- When creating a new paragraph library item at */admin/content/paragraphs/add/default* there is no language selector. Library items are always in the page's default language: English.
  [image: Add Paragraphs library item without language selector]
- In the "Paragraphs library item settings - Manage form display" the default field "Language" with the widget "Language select" is present. (*/admin/config/content/paragraphs_library_item/form-display*)
  [image: Manage form display with langauge field]
- In "Configuration - Regional and language" at */admin/config/regional/content-language* there is a check box for "Paragraphs library item". If I tick this checkbox and save the page, it reloads and the tick is gone. I'm not able to enable "Paragraphs library item" in "Custom language settings" here. I do not get any error in the "Recent log messages" either.
  [image: Content language settings]
- Below on this same page (*/admin/config/regional/content-language*) there is the default paragraph type entry "From library". I have enabled this like I did with my other paragraphs.
  [image: Paragraph Type From library]

What am I missing to enable language support for paragraphs library items?
Thank you for you help and suggestions in advance!

Comment: I'm in the same boat right now. Did you figure this out?

Comment: No, I made a workaround. I have solved this by creating a new custom content type called "Paragraph Library", containing only one unlimited paragraph field "field_predefined_paragraph"; ticking the paragraph types you want. Reuseable content can be saved as a new node in the content type "Paragraph Library", which contains paragraphs. Of course I also created a new paragraph type "Paragraph Library" containing one Entity Reference field field_reuseable_paragraph, ticking only the content type "Paragraph Library".
Now you can add your reuseable content using the paragraph "Paragraph Library".

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but I solved it the following way:

- Make sure to tick "Paragraphs library item" in "Custom language settings" section
- After that, scroll down (without saving) to the section "Paragraphs library item" and tick "Paragraphs library item" + fields to be translated.
- Save your settings